# Understanding why Meanwell LDD-350H outputs > 350mA current

Tags: led, led-driver

I built a LED light for my aquarium. I used 140 various 1 W power LEDs, driven by 14 constant current [Meanwell LDD-350H](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LDD-H/LDD-H-SPEC.PDF) drivers. Each driver is handling between 8 and 11 LEDs. I use 36 V power supply. I tested it with multimeter and to my surprise it turned out to draw 8.8 A at full brightness (>300W).

When I test individual channels between driver output and LED string it reads 350 mA for WFS and Blue LED strings, but for 7k, 9k and 10k whites it's 0.6-0.75 A. Royal Blues string reads 1.23 A. Some LEDs are dual chip. Each string contains only LEDs of one type. Behavior is the same no matter to which one of 14 drivers I connect certain string. I have 3 separate strings for each 4 types of white LEDs and each string of the type shares the same characteristics. I tested with two very cheap multimeters and measurements were consistent. Not sure if I can trust those though. What may I be dealing with here? How to troubleshoot? Or maybe this is just some issue with testing those with cheap multimeters?

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: What’s the acceptable Vf range for your drivers?

Comment: The driver drops 3V, so the voltage drop of each LED string must be less than 33V. Thats my guess for the white LEDs. For royal blue, have you accidentally connected vin- to vout-? the driver likely uses low side switching, so if you did that you would bypass the current limiting of the driver.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check whether any of these multi-chip LEDs might have a common cathode or anode?

Comment: I had a basic course of electronics 10+ years ago at my university, but my focus was on computer science, so it's fair to call me an amateur. Please correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that even if I exceeded driver's Vf ability the worst that could happen is I'd underdrive LEDs, but not increase power. I will double check for -vin -vout shortage tomorrow, but it's unlikely I would mess it up with all 14 channels and it would affect only few types of LEDs. Multi-chip ones are in fact dual-chip with two output leads (+/-), so I didn't pay attention to its internal structure.

Comment: Try measuring with only one driver active at a time. And check for strange things like more than one series branch lighting up.

Comment: After some though I came to the conclusion that Drew's suggestion about -Vin and -Vout being connected is the easiest explanation. Although there was no continuity between those pins detected on any driver, I guess some current must have been flowing between those pins. I wasn't able to find the root cause, but after desoldering one driver and testing it it acted as expected.